# Pure Math or Stats undegrad for Stats Grad School

Tags: soft-question

Hello I'm currently a first year undergrad double majoring in physics and math. My school offers both a pure math and a statistics concentration and I'm wondering which one would be better for potential grad school in statistics. It would be a little bit easier to fit in the statistics route but it also doesn't seems to provide the same level of rigor. I was hoping I could get some advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: What would you like to do later ?